# In unity 3d, how to add texture to 3d object(.fbx )?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures

[image]

In unity 3d, how to add texture to 3d object(.fbx )? Drag  and drop material with texture onto 3d object works for default object(eg:cube) but not to downloaded 3d objects(umbrella)? I could get only the color not the texture.

Answer (score 0):

If you want apply a texture to 3D object it need UV map. For example in blender :`https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics`

I think it exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

if You are adding fbx in project, the sequence will be

1. First add textures
2. Then, models.

Comment: Hi, adding textures to what? without adding the models where will we add texture? I need to change the texture of the model.

Comment: fbx and textures are two things. whenever you want to import fbx in the unity project you must add your fbx texure first in unity3d in any folder. This is the sequence. if you added your fbx first and after that its tetxture, then it will not apply texture to fbx

Comment: And if you are want to change the texture then you should require to set its uv.